# Why can't I make a document in explorer

Tags: 18.04

This is extremely frustrating. I like to create documents from file explorer. Why would this be removed from Ubuntu 18.04?

Apparently this a design decision. There is no incentive for me to switch to this new release, let alone use any Ubuntu versions lacking this feature. Too much regression.

The workaround by creating a template <strike>doesn't even work for me, either.</strike> Is working now.

Comment: By File Explorer (the name of windows file manager) I assume you mean Nautilus or it's new name Files. Nautilus was the file manager used by older GNOME, and has changed name to Files under the newer version of GNOME found in Ubuntu 18.04. If this isn't what you mean, you should provide more information, as it's still there.

Comment: I'm simply  speaking about the default fire explorer on a fresh install of Ubuntu. Clicking on the icon 'Files'.  I can add a new folder, but not a new file/document. This is with the most recent version of Ubuntu 18.04.1. Along this this, there is the option missing to open as root, and open in terminal. These were extremely useful for me. Linux Mint has these still.

Comment: I'm not a gnome (or unity) user so rarely use Files, but if you go to icon view (*top right command icons, second from left for me*) you can click on the white background (white on my 'theme', may differ for you) then a menu appears which has "new folder, new document ..." and a lot more options, including "open in terminal"; at least on mine it does.   Open as root won't work with wayland and was removed by GNOME I believe (but this is from memory and was late last year I think..)

Comment: Creating a template is supposed to work, did you create the template in the correct directory? Is your system language non-English?

Comment: @ guiverc, yes, after trying out many ditros, it seems the problem is Wayland. In Gnome atm, there is only 'a new folder' option. No 'new document' or 'new file'.

Comment: @ pomskey:  My system is English. I succeeded in creating a template, and this time it is working. Last time I installed Ubuntu the option disappeared on it's own after a few reboots, and refused to display while using nautilus in a root folder. Time will tell if it will do it again.

Comment: @RyanWC you can always drop GNOME Nautilus and choose other normal fully functional file-manager such as Thunar, Caja or Nemo. Or drop whole GNOME desktop and replace it with Xfce, MATE or Cinnamon.

Comment: @N0rbert I wish that was a good solution. Unfortunately Gnome is the only one with correct Wacom support. All the others either don't allow the binding of modifier keys, or they don't correctly deal with the toggle buttons. I used to use a script that relied on udev and systemd, but it doesn't work anymore. The only distro that works with Wacom is SUSE, but that has it's own problems like black screen when installing Nvidia drivers.